# How can I read and reply with any notification (Any App Notification) through other bluetooth device with iPhone by using BLE+BT

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I want to read notification through BLE + BT and perform some operation on the bases of notification.

Like any Smart Watch or Apple Watch, they get notification through iPhone and send to smart watch with the help of BLE.

**I want to read all notification and write (Reply) to notification if possible (like Whatsapp) through fermware.**

**Now question is :**

1. Is that possible to do(read and reply) to notification with the help of BLE.
2. If yes then is MFi is reaquired for this
3. or what is the exact way to do this (Read/Reply to all notification)

**I got some Apple Documentation :**

Apple Notification Center Service (ANCS) Specification

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/AppleNotificationCenterServiceSpecification/Introduction/Introduction.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/AppleNotificationCenterServiceSpecification/Specification/Specification.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013460-CH1-SW7

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/AppleNotificationCenterServiceSpecification/Appendix/Appendix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013460-CH3-SW7

Comment: Yes, ANCS is what you need to use. The answers to your questions are in those documents

Comment: MFi is needed for this ? And when i try to understand the documents i am not sure about how to reply to any notifications ?

Comment: No.  ANCS doesn't require MFi mmbership

Comment: @Paulw11 Thats great ...

Comment: @Paulw11 Can you mention that perticular area where apple metion about replying to the notifications ? Or you can share any specific documents with me so that i can understand easily ?

Comment: @Paulw11 I am able to read all notifications but i am not able to reply. Is that possible to reply notifications throuth ANCS ?

Comment: It is not possible to generate a customised reply.  All you can do is return a positive or negative action to the notification